# Resizing graphics in Mathematica

Tags: graphics

My Mathematica graphics are very big documents (more than 20 M). How can I make them smaller (not more than 1 M)?

Comment: Need more info. What kind of graphics? How are you creating them? 20M is megabytes? Does `ImageSize`/`ImageResize` not do the trick?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to create these sorts of images?

Comment: Dunlon@      ParametricPlot3D[{Re[E^(I s)/(9 p) + p 8/9 E^(I s)], 
  Im[E^(I s)/(9 p) + 8/9 E^(I s) p], 4/9 Sqrt[2] Log[1/p]}, {p, 1/2, 
  1}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 2 ]

Comment: What is 'Dunlon'?

Comment: If, of course, exporting is what you want to do, which is unclear from your question.

Comment: You probably want to convert a `Graphics[]` object to an `Image[]` object by rasterizing it.